# Как в QTableWidget вывести кнопку?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Доброго времени суток.

Работаю с PyQt5, пытаюсь в таблице, а именно, в последней колонке таблицы вывести кнопку. Как это можно сделать?

```
 self.Btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
 self.Btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 10, 90, 30))
 self.Btn.setObjectName("Btn")

 self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem('Текст'))
 self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem('Текст1'))
 self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem(self.Btn.clicked.connect(self.LoadData)))
```

Спасибо

Comment: Зачем вы передаете вызов метода `connect` от кнопки self.Btn в QTableWidgetItem?

Comment: потому что мне нужно запустить функцию `LoadData`

Comment: В данной строчке вы не выполняете функцию `LoadData`, а соединияете сигнал `clicked` с методом `LoadData`. Данная строчка должна быть написана отдельно от `QTableWidgetItem`. Иначе получается ерунда, так как `connect` возвращает `None`, а вы его передаете в `QTableWidgetItem`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для установки виджета в ячейку таблицы можно воспользоваться методом `setCellWidget`

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = Qt.QHBoxLayout(self)
        table = Qt.QTableWidget()
        table.setRowCount(2)
        table.setColumnCount(2)
        btn = Qt.QPushButton("Some button")
        table.setCellWidget(0, 0, btn)
        layout.addWidget(table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Отлично, работает. Спасибо!