# Маштабируемый QTableWidget при растяжении окна

Tags: python, pyqt5

Доброго времени суток.

Работаю с PyQt5, имеется окно программы с `QTableWidget` внутри. Размер окна задан вручную `MainWindow.resize(796, 499)`.
При запуске видим такую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столбцов больше чем может вместиться в окне, соответственно появляется скролл.

Я, как обычный пользователь, хочу растянуть окно, что бы видеть сразу все столбцы, тяну за край окна и вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Растягивается окно а не сама таблица.

Собственно, напрашивается вопрос, как сделать, что бы таблица была зафиксирована с правой стороны и при растягивании окна она тоже растягивались?

Спасибо!

Comment: Используйте менеджеры компоновки, такие как `QVBoxLayout`, `QHBoxLayout`, `QGridLayout`. Они позволяют автоматически размещать элементы и масштабировать их без указания аюсолютных значений. Посмотрите код из моего ответа на ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723770/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-qtablewidget-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83

Comment: @Avernial посмотрел, попробовал сделать через QHBoxLayout. Нацепил на главное окно.  Таблица стала маштабированной, только вот она растянулась на все окно и сдвинулась вверх, под кнопки

Comment: Так вы и кнопки должны в Layout вставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для масшатибрования элементов необходимо использовать менеджеры компоновки. Менеджеры компоновки могут быть вложены друг в друга, что обеспечивает удобное добавление и масштабирование всех элементов.

Вот простой пример с кнопками и таблицей.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        btn_layout = Qt.QHBoxLayout()

        btn1 = Qt.QPushButton("Button 1")
        btn2 = Qt.QPushButton("Button 2")
        btn3 = Qt.QPushButton("Button 3")

        btn_layout.addWidget(btn1)
        btn_layout.addWidget(btn2)
        btn_layout.addWidget(btn3)

        table = Qt.QTableWidget()
        table.setRowCount(10)
        table.setColumnCount(10)
        layout.addWidget(table)
        layout.addLayout(btn_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Для того чтобы элементы не растягивались можно использовать специальный элемент `QSpacerItem`.
Например добавьте такую строку:

```
btn_layout.addItem(Qt.QSpacerItem(0, 0, Qt.QSizePolicy.Expanding, Qt.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
```

После строки

```
btn_layout = Qt.QHBoxLayout()
```

Кнопку будут поджаты к правому краю.